# Certificate usage order in Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate

In which order are resolved(used) certificates in Windows (10)?

I have for current server self-signed certificate in trusted root and for the same server I have certificate signed by our CA in Personal, both are on Local Machine level.
Which certificate will be used when needed?

Is there hierarchy for resolving certificates?
e.g. local machine root - personal - current user root - ...

Comment: Used by what? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: When you send a request to the server and the server requires certificate. Which one will be used? The one in root or Personal?

Comment: What application or API is the question? Browser (which one?), WinHTTP, .NET... I think there is no general anwer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about API that is available on the server. Request is send via Postman or Swagger. As a browser we can assume Chrome. The API endpoint is written in .NET.

Comment: So, then the question is: is it IIS? Then a certificate is explicitly bound. Otherwise it has less to do with windows as the developer of the API is in charge.